# How to id print the value of the variable in res.json(message: {})

Tags: express

I want to print the value of orderId in the message section of res.json() but I am getting the exact string after the $ symbol

```
 if(order.length > 0)
        {
          res.status(200).json(order);
        }
        else{
          res.json({message: 'No orders Found with orderId ${orderId}'});
        }
      }).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Comment: I can't understand the issue; could you elaborate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 if(order.length > 0)
        {
          res.status(200).json(order);
        }
        else{
          res.json({message: `No orders Found with orderId ${orderId}`});
        }
      }).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

use ` (back-ticks) instead of ' (single quotes).
ES6 Template Strings